# How to do an "ellipsis" like effect for non string elements and restrict rows up to 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

The goal is to do this:

[image]

The problem is that at the end of the row 2 I need to add two "harcoded" things:

- The "# more" button (only when is needed)
- The "face-plus" button (always)

This is the "ellipsis" effect I am asking about.

I have tried the following:

```
// HTML
<div class="container">
  <div class="children">
    Hola1
  </div>
   <div class="children">
    Hola2
  </div>
   <div class="children">
    Hola3
  </div>
    <div class="children">
    Hola4
  </div>
   <div class="children">
    Hola5
  </div>
   <div class="children">
    Hola6
  </div>
</div>

// css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 80px; // this makes the trick of having 2 rows
  overflow: hidden; // this makes the trick of having 2 rows
}

.children {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

and I get this result:

[image]

but I am not being able to add the "fixed" elements at the end of the line 2 because I have more hidden elements on the list.

Some key points:

- width of elements is dynamic
- I want a maximum of 2 rows.
- at the end of the row 2 I need to have the "# more" button (only when needed) and the face icon.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the badges are inline-block they'll wrap but you'll have to grab the height of the container it all sits in to determine when you've reached the 2 lines, then sum the widths of the child badges to determine where to break what's shown and append the "more" badge with count. Have you made any attempts so far or are you just sharing your requirements?

Comment: I've not tried but I have thought about it. The thing is that I will need to display an approximated amount of children and, after that, I will need to get them from the document in order to know theirs width and also calculate the width of the parent container and make the numbers. But the problem is that I will need to display the elements first. Right?

Comment: Yea, in the past when I've done this sort of thing I would grab the `offsetHeight` of the parent and same with the width (to include any potential borders in the size of the parent element. Then loop through the children to get their widths including the width of the static trailing buttons. Then you have to figure out how many can fit on each row with the trailing buttons on the second, remove the overflows and ++ the count for the "more" badge etc. Unfortunately takes a bit more time and work than many want to volunteer on here though, sorry.

Comment: Oh and you'll also have to a re-eval of the sizes when the counts on the badges are increased since like a single digit will expand a badges width as counts increase to multiple digits etc.

Comment: Yes, and also I will need to add listeners to know when the screen is resized. So there is no chance to avoid displaying and recalculating.

Comment: Yea, it's not a quick answer scenario unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to do fiddly bits of arithmetic you could clear the container, and add the elements one at a time, seeing if the one you have just added (plus its associated 'more' element and icon) go outside the bottom of the container.

If it has gone outside the bottom then go back one, so the more statement is correct.

I do not know whether you intended to put the more statement and icon into the DOM (or whether perhaps through a pseudo element having left space for them). This snippet has them in the DOM so you can click on the more element and do whatever you want to do then.

And you will have to run this code on each load and resize.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //just in case there's a little flash as we add the elements
const cbottom = container.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
const children = document.querySelectorAll('.children');
const num = children.length;

container.innerHTML = '<div class="moreEl"><span class="remainder">xxx</span> MORE</div><img src="youricon.jpg" style="width: 20px; aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;">';
const moreEl = container.querySelector('.moreEl');
const remainder = moreEl.querySelector('span');

// now add each child one at a time, with either the 'nn more' plus icon or just the icon in front of it until the child is outside the container when step back one
let i = 0;
for (i; i < children.length; i++) {
  remainder.innerHTML = num - i - 1;
  container.insertBefore(children[i], moreEl);

  if ((children[i].getBoundingClientRect().top > cbottom) || (moreEl.getBoundingClientRect().top >= cbottom)) {
    // can't get this element in, let alone with any associated more element, so go back one
    children[i].parentElement.removeChild(children[i]);
    remainder.innerHTML = num - i;
    break;
  }
}

if (i >= (num - 1)) {
  moreEl.parentElement.removeChild(moreEl);
} else {
  for (let j = i; j < num; j++) {
    container.append(children[j]);
  }
}
container.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  /* this makes the trick of having 2 rows */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* this makes the trick of having 2 rows */
}

.children {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.moreEl {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="children">
    Hola1
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola2
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola3
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola4
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola5
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola6
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola7
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola8
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola9
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    Hola10
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: this snippet has more 'Hola' elements so it's easier to test out different container widths.

Comment: Awesome. I will try it but I think that this does most of the job. Thanks!